# Why k8s with minikube NodePort are not working?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, networking, nginx, ports

I am using minikube on my windows 11 machine just to start testing k8s. And my NodePorts are not giving an URL, and even when I recover the service's I.P and ports by using `kubectl describe` and I use that i.p and port in my browser they don't work.

I've remade the steps in a imperative simple form to simplify this question. I have followed this exact steps:

1. `kubectl run --image=nginx nginx-test`
2. `kubectl expose pod nginx-test --port=80 --type=NodePort`
3. `minikube service list --profile=testing`

From the third step I was expecting to see the URL of my newly created NodePort service. The new service `nginx-test` is in the list, but the URL column is empty (as all other NodePorts I have created in other examples, either declarative or imperative)

So after I didn't saw a URL, I though I might just get the new service's i.p by running `minikube ip --profile=testing` and it's `192.168.49.2` . Then for the port it used on my host PC I got it from `kubect describe svc nginx-test` and got this output.

```
Name:                     nginx-test
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=nginx-test
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=nginx-test
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.97.19.169
IPs:                      10.97.19.169
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30034/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.71:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

It says it's 30034 (though, it says `<unset>` which sounds like the problem but I don't know what it means).

So anyway, I opened a new browser with cleared cache and went to 192.168.49.2:30034 but I get no result. I've also tried localhost:30034 and same problem.

What am I missing here for the Nodeport truly listen?

Comment: Try following these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767164/expose-port-in-minikube